# relastionship не работает с null-значениями

Tags: laravel, relation

Всем привет!
Создал отношения в laravel, и все работает до тех пор пока не встретится null значения, помогите разобраться, заранее спасибо!

модель User:

```
public function issues()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Issues', 'worker');
}
```

модель Issues:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'worker');
}
```

Таблица Issues:

```
    Schema::table('issues', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('worker')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('worker')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Представление:

```
            @foreach($issues as $issue)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $issue->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ $issue->user->name }}</td>
            </tr>                
            @endforeach
```

Пока все внешние ключи указаны все работает, как встречается null, то получаем ошибку **Trying to get property of non-object**, гуглил, но что-то все там не то.

Comment: Ну, а что ты ожидаешь увидеть ? У тебя ж нет связки, т.е. отношение возвращает null, и затем ты от null пытаешься взять name `{{ $issue->user ? $issue->user->name:'' }}`

Comment: Вернее сказать связка есть, а вот у null имени нет...да, верно....эх. Спасибо!)